# How to convert XML namespaces to Clojure namespaces during XML parse?

Tags: xml, parsing, clojure, xml-namespaces

How to convert XML namespaces to Clojure namespaces during parse?
For example with `clojure.data.zip.xml` lib.

Is it possible by connecting external parser though?

For example, we have XSD file with a number of declared namespaces inside schema tag and some of them are used in definition below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by Fujitsu Interstage XWand B0237 -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-10-31/tab/FR_1_001_01c_01"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:FR_1_001_01c_01="http://www.cbr.ru/xbrl/bfo/rep/2017-10-31/tab/FR_1_001_01c_01"
            xmlns:model="http://www.eurofiling.info/xbrl/ext/model"
            xmlns:ifrs-full="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/taxonomy/2015-03-11/ifrs-full"
            xmlns:label="http://xbrl.org/2008/label"
            xmlns:ca="http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/consistency"
            xmlns:rol_ifric_2_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ifric_2_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:rol_sic_27_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_sic_27_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:rol_ias_7_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ias_7_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:va="http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/value"
            xmlns:xfi="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/function/instance"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:mf="http://xbrl.org/2008/filter/match"
            xmlns:rol_ias_10_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ias_10_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:rol_ias_27_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ias_27_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:rol_ifrs_13_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ifrs_13_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:rol_ifrs_8_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ifrs_8_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xmlns:ea="http://xbrl.org/2008/assertion/existence"
            xmlns:rol_ifrs_4_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ifrs_4_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:ref="http://www.xbrl.org/2006/ref"
            xmlns:bf="http://xbrl.org/2008/filter/boolean"
            xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
            xmlns:rol_ias_19_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ias_19_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:msg="http://xbrl.org/2010/message"
            xmlns:gen="http://xbrl.org/2008/generic"
            xmlns:rol_ias_23_2015-03-11="http://xbrl.ifrs.org/role/ifrs/rol_ias_23_2015-03-11"
            xmlns:num="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/numeric"
            xmlns:pf="http://xbrl.org/2007/filter/period"
```

So I would like to create correspondent namespaces for clojure keyword in map representing data parsed from XML files according to this XSD.

Comment: @AlanThompson I extended question

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired behavior? Can you show how the namespaces are to be used?  For example, do you want to output xml tags with the namespace a la Clojure "my.namespace/some-tag"?

Comment: Clojure keyword namespacing and Clojure var namespacing are different. keyword namespaces are probably what you want?