# Why ns aliasing inside NON-global scope (let, def) is not working?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

Trying to alias ns inside let to be able to use it locally, but got an error `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: sss` when just trying to use alias

```
(ns core 
  (:require [clojure.set]
            [clojure.string])
)

(let [] 
     (alias 'sss 'clojure.string)
     (println (ns-aliases *ns*) "hi1")
     (println (sss/capitalize "hONdURas"))
     ;(println (clojure.string/capitalize "hONdURas")) ;;this works
     (ns-unalias *ns*  'sss)
     (+ 1 2)
)

(println (ns-aliases *ns*))
```

https://repl.it/repls/NoxiousRubberyComputationallinguistics

Comment: Not specific to `let`. `(def testd (do (alias 'sss 'clojure.string) (sss/trim "")))` and `((fn [] (alias 'sss 'clojure.string) (sss/trim "")))` are the same. Looks like `alias` must be top-level.

Comment: It's pity :( I was hoping to use aliases similar to SQL-way when in each select I can use the same alias for very different tables because they are local for each query

Comment: Also strange thing that just putting ```(alias 'sss 'clojure.string)``` do not results in any error

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your use case there, but it might be possible to hack something together using a macro. And I wouldn't expect that that would cause an error. It seems as though the `alias` is just being ignored.

Comment: Interestingly, the alias *is* registering: `(let []
  (alias 'b 'clojure.string)
  (println "NS:" (ns-aliases *ns*)))` outputs
           
`NS: {b #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x66bd2083 clojure.string]}`. If you try and *use* the alias however, the whole thing fails with a compiler exception before the `println` can even run. This almost looks like a bug.

Comment: Use case is quite staight. For example I had 20 DBMS complex tables. And I want to made some validations and transformations, joins etc. So I am goint to put each of them to ns. But then it's dull to use it's full ns names, so I suppose to use local aliases for each needed table. Say ```t``` in one ```let``` be *tTable1* and the same ```t``` will be for *tTable2* in other ```let```

Comment: That use case seems kind of odd honestly. You ran into an interesting question here, but I suspect this is an XY Problem. I don't use SQL, so I might still be misunderstanding, but I've never had a need to do what you're describing.

Comment: Well, without respect to SQL and tables, I am just trying to realize how to use ns-s in Clojure :) 
Another problem I've faces is [converting XML  ns to Clojure ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992173/how-to-convert-xml-namespaces-to-clojure-namespaces-during-xml-parse). So many unclear moments

Comment: @Carcigenicate `(let [] ...)` is not always the same as `(do ...)`. At the top level of a file, each subexpression in a `(do ...)` is compiled and executed separately. Conversely, `(let [] ...)` follows the usual evaluation rules, compiling the entire expression (including all subexpressions) at once before evaluating it. This can make a difference if you're changing the environment, for example by adding namespace aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(alias ...) doesn't have to be top level. The way clojure works is that there is something called the *reader* that takes text data and turns it into data structures that are inputs to the compiler. See

https://clojure.org/reference/reader

Any namespaces referred to in the code have to already be defined for the reader prior to use. (Similarly for functions).

So, in

```
(let [] 
    (alias 'sss 'clojure.string)
    (println (sss/capitalize "aaa")))
```

the alias hasn't been assigned when the reader is trying to turn

```
(sss/capitalize)
```

into data.

Comment: Do you mean that ```alias``` also defines [temporal] namespace as require does? 
(temporal because ```ns-unalias``` can be done)

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by [temporal]? (alias ...) is exactly like :as in require, see https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4230

Comment: Seems I understand that problem not in alias but in reading ```sss/``` . Well, I wished there was smth like  (the-ns 'sss) for aliases then :/

Comment: Exactly. The reader doesn't know what data to turn that sequence of characters into.

Comment: Pity. I was thinking to reuse the same small names (like t,p,r...) as aliases in local scope, just like when we write SQL-queries and use aliases for tables

Comment: I was proposed such solution instead. Seems not bad
```(let [sss 'clojure.string]
  ((ns-resolve sss 'capitalize) "test"))```

Comment: Also, try `ns-interns` which returns a map of all ns symbols instead of resolving them one by one.

Comment: Well- thinking of var namespaces in the context of local scope is non-idiomatic clojure, and also it doesn't really make sense. Aliases point to var namespaces, which are the machinery of dependency resolution. Var namespaces are, by definition, clojure's equivalent to module scope Using local aliases would be similar to doing a (def ...) or a (defn ) inside of a let. And they're not concurrency safe.